# Is `Response.Flush()` meaningful if i use `Response.End()` directly afterwards?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use to end my transmission to the client by flushing and ending as in the code below.

```
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

However, it just hit me that `Response.End()` flushes the buffered contents to the client. So is there any point using both in a sequence?

Comment: Response.End is abnormal end of thread and invoke the event EndRequest.
Response.Flush : All currently buffered output force sent to the client

Comment: You should use `CompleteRequest()` on the HttpApplication object to end the request (and continue processing if you want.)  Do NOT use `Response.End`.  Read up on why.  The accepted answer eventually uses it, but is there a _really_ good reason you are using an exception to kill the response thread?

Comment: @AndrewBacker Nope, there is not. Unless you count "i've always done so so it come automatically to use it" as a really good reason. You mean one should flush first and then complete, right? I'll just go Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; Response.Write(GetXmlData().InnerXml); Response.Flush(); Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
 Great info.

Comment: Yes, that will close it and flush at the same time, and basically just skip to the end of processing.  `Response.End()` is what we all used with classic asp, and I think it just carried over.  I hadn't even run into `CompleteRequest()` until a few years ago... maybe it was there in samples, but I just skipped it because I already _knew_ hah.

Comment: Actually, i got errors when i served a XML-file and finished with `CompleteRequest` so i was forced to change it back. I'm not sure why it didn't work. Something about illegal characters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no, but there's important differences between the two:

**`Response.Flush()`** is useful for writing portions of a response before all processing has completed (that is, if response buffering is disabled). Any code following Flush() will continue to execute and any prior Response.Write()s will be flushed to the client.

**`Response.End()`** is a little more brutal... It will not only abort the current thread, but in doing so it'll throw a ThreadAbort exception and kill the current request. Any code following Response.End() will never see the light of day unless you handle the exception properly.

As you pointed out, End() will flush your buffered content anyways. In some cases End() will actually call Flush() internally, specifically, if the context is not cancellable:

```
public void End()
{
    if (this._context.IsInCancellablePeriod)
    {
        InternalSecurityPermissions.ControlThread.Assert();
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(new HttpApplication.CancelModuleException(false));
    }
    else if (!this._flushing)
    {
        this.Flush();
        this._ended = true;
        if (this._context.ApplicationInstance != null)
        {
            this._context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```